# How to roleplay a divine character in Ravenloft?

Tags: dnd-4e, roleplaying, ravenloft

My cleric just got sucked into the Demi-plane of Dread.  I've been told that his connection to Moradin has been completely severed, but my spells still work.

How should I roleplay that?
Are there any other limitations on divine characters in Ravenloft?

Comment: If this is indeed a 4E game, any answers are going to be a problem because there is no official 4E Ravenloft that I can find. Neither S&S nor WotC.

Comment: @aramis According to my DM there is a blurb about it in the manual of the planes, in the Shadowfell section.

Comment: @C. Ross: Not exactly right. It's not the "demi-plane of dread", but the "Domains of Dread" on the Shadowfell demi-plane. It's not Ravenloft, and no mention is made at all of Ravenloft in the book. It has some similarities, and a LOT of differences.

Comment: @aramis Alas, we must be playing homebrew then.  Woe is me.

Comment: Most have taken the blurb to be a reference to Ravenloft. Wot announced that Ravenloft will be coming back officially next year, though in the meantime I'm using Jester's rules updates.

Comment: @C. Ross: Nothing inherently wrong with homebrew... other than it means any questions being asked can't be answered in any authoritative way. Note that my answer was grounded in AD&D2E Ravenloft Domains of Dread hardcover and D&D3.X Ravenloft HC from S&S, not the 4E Shadowfell.

Comment: @Aramis: could you add your reference list from this comment to your answer? It added a lot of weight to the answer when I finally caught the comment (it was originally under the "click here for more comments" link).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

three approaches come to mind:

1. since he still gets higher than 3rd level spells, he knows he's not totally cut off from Moradin. He might thus take it as a test from Moradin.
2. He might take the lack of instruction as being cut off, and see the spells as being provided by others, instead. He may seek to find out who it is providing his higher level spells, but assume they are not hostile. (This is typical for spelljammer familiar characters...)
3. He might decide he's been cut off, and some other god is trying to lure him off. In which case, he might actually refuse to use his magic.

And yes, there are a lot of changes to which spells work, and how many work. And turning is altered, too. Nothing your character does will allow him to talk to his deity unless said deity is one of those trapped on the demi-plane.

*Note:* This answer based upon the Ravenloft *Domains of Dread* Hardcover for AD&D 2E and the Ravenloft hardcover for 3E by Sword and Sorcery, as well as *Spelljammer* for AD&D 2E.

Comment: It wasn't 4E tagged when I answered. It was just D&D tagged. And I can't find evidence of a 4E version out yet, either, so earlier edition is in play, or a homebrew is.

Comment: @Logos7 I think the answer is still perfectly fine.  I'm looking for role-playing suggestions, not exact game mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

You could justify that his spells still work as a result of his true faith, but perhaps they are weaker because his deity is not actively supporting him?

Answer (score 1):

The Manual of the Planes blurb for 4e refers to a Domain of Dread by name but not Ravenloft. Domains of Dread are located deep in the Shadowfell and are created by some odd power to be nigh inescapable unless its lord is destroyed.

To help roleplaying a divine character in ravenloft, one should consider the properties of ravenloft as a plane.

The Shadowfell has normal gravity, normal maliability in a world much like the mortal world, except for one thing, sources of light are muted, normal light sources give half the diameter of light.

The Domains of Dread are the same as the shadowfell except for the A> Mists B> Dark Lord

the Mists surround the Domains of Dread and prevent creatures from leaving.

The Darklord, while normally also the nominal lord, has some degree of control or maliability over his domain. The Book doesn't mention if this is conscious or explicit control, or if its more reactive, simular to the Fey Demenses  that the book also mentions and refers to here.

As for escape, that normally only happens when the Dark lord has been slain.

As for the old fluff, The only really important bits I think are the Dark Powers that be, Ie the forces that make the Domains of Dread in the beginning and want to contain the Dark lords for whatever reason. As these powers are canonically unstated and are little more than plot devices, there is no real need to 'do'anything with or for them, except perhaps off a little corruption and make vague and ominous reference to them.

As for how to play your priest, the Domains of Dread do little but offer a sinister feeling and half light radius for normal light sources (plus or minus any particular details of the domain). Your priest knows that your powers won't suddenly turn off because your invested by powers by your superiors. Divine Casters are given their holy powers once, during their ordination and it remains on presumably forever, or until specifically recalled.

As for what sinister feelings and isolation can drive someone to do? That's up to you, but less has almost certainly destroyed greater men.

Comment: Could you clarify about this investment stuff? That didn't make any sense to me (a non-4e player) until I read your comment below. It's still fuzzy, and very relevant to the question it seems.

Comment: the other bit is a comment not really an answer, i see no particular reason to change it, unless you feel this answer is unclear about something.

Comment: Yes, it's unclear. The first time I read it I didn't see a real answer anywhere in it. It required the context of your other comment to understand this answer.

Comment: I think this answer would be improved by citing a 4e rulebook that says clerics have divine power invested in them only during ordination and that continued contact with their deity thereafter is unnecessary.